# Sharing household address with individual record no longer builds "member of household" relationship CiviCRM v5.17.0

Tags: relationships, addresses, households

We noticed after upgrading to CiviCRM v5.17.0 that when you create a new individual record, and add an address and have it shared with another Household record's address, the option to automatically build the "household member of" relationship no longer happens automatically like it used to.

We DID notice that if one shares the address with an ORGANIZATIONAL record, there is a toggle to set that organizational record as the employer, which then updates the "employer" field AND also builds the "employee of" relationship.

Is there any way to restore the automatic relationship linking with the household record when an address is shared with an individual record from a household record? Or at least generate a toggle button to create the relationship on save?

Comment: Any updates here? Looks like a lot of folks are looking at this, but don't seem to have an answer. You can see this functionality in the online demo as well.

Comment: Same on CiviCRM 5.13.4. Which version came before stop working? Seems a regression. There is an issue open on https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/1319

Comment: @FrancescBassasiBullich - thanks for the heads up! Been waiting on this for a while....

Answer (score 2):

While this question is old - just indicating that this was added as a feature at some point. There's a checkbox to indicate you'd like to also add the household relationship if you choose to share an address from a household.

[image]

Comment: Yes, and it's not working.

Comment: What version of CiviCRM are you running and on what CMS? The screenshot above is from the dmaster site running 5.46 and I tested it does work. I can also confirm it works on CiviCRM 5.39 (Drupal 7)

Comment: Civi 5.40.2 on Drupal 7